# How to show year of all incoming SMS on Android 14 (Pixel 6)?

Tags: sms, android-14

I have a Pixel 6 phone and noticed that the year of incoming text messages is not shown if they are less than a year old. Is is possible to enable display of the year on all messages?

For example, I have a message showing "Tuesday 14th March 2023"  since it is more than a year old, but the next one only shows "Thursday 30th March" since it is less than a year.

I'm using the built-in app for SMS on this phone, and if this is possible with another app, I'm willing to switch.

Comment: I use [simple SMS from F-Droid store](https://f-droid.org/de/packages/com.simplemobiletools.smsmessenger/) and it always shows me the date of an SMS. Not sure if you really have to switch the default SMS app as Android has a central SMS database. So you should be able to just view the SMS using this app.